# How you deploy your reports (with Reporting Services)

Tags: deployment, reporting-services

Which one you choose?

- Use the Deploy feature in VS
- Build a rss script and execute it through rs.exe
- Build a deployment package
- Another option

Keep in mind that in many of your environments the report developers/designers don't have publish role in Reporting Server.

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468674/deploying-sql-server-reporting-services-reports-on-production-boxes The scripter tool is definitely an alternative for building the rss script.

Answer (score 2):

In Dev, we use the deploy feature in VS.
In Prod, our Prod support team will either upload them manually from the ReportServer website (if it's just one or two reports) or use a simple report upload utility that we wrote.  The utility uses the SSRS web service.

Answer (score 0):

For the developers we have a custom built ReportDeployer where we choose what environment to deploy to (development, test, production) and branch to deploy from (also development, test, production). There is a config file with all the reports available for deployment along with their directory structure.
 For production builds, the ReportDeployer has a command line interface and our build script pulls the latest reports from the Prod branch in TFS, then deploys all using our custom app.

Answer (score 0):

Developers can publish to development using the deploy command in visual studio.
Admins move the reports from dev to prd with rsscripter.

Answer (score 0):

We use rss scripts to get all reports from a folder and upload them to the given Report Server.