# Deploying Sql Server Reporting Services reports on production boxes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

How to deploy Sql server reports on productions boxes?
Locally it's not a problem, I just specify the url and then right click on project and say deploy which deploy on my local server.

But it's not gonna be the case for the production server

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recommend you create rs scripts that can be executed on production server. Take a look at Reporting Services Scripter. It's creates deployment scripts based on your current installation.

http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=62

Answer (score 3):

Either:

1. Upload the RDL file through the web interface.
2. Connect to Reporting Services from SQL Management Studio and upload the RDL through that interface.